# Django REST Framework serializer validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How exactly do I use validators in my serializers? I have currently create my validators in `app/validators.py` and have my serializers in `app/serializers.py`.

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    item_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        validators = [validate_item_date]
        fields = ('item_id', 'item_date')

from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
```

validators.py

```
def validate_item_date(item_date):
    if item_date < {something}:
        raise ValidationError('')
```

My question basically: do I provide the `item_date` as parameter here or does it not work like this?

Answer (score 1):

DRF allows for field level validation. Have your function name as: def validate_(fieldname). and drf will run that function against the corresponding field name. In the code below, "validate_item_date", drf corresponds that to the field "item_date".

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_date = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item

    def validate_item_date(self, value):
        if value < 10:
            raise ValidationError('')
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation to serializer like this

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_item_date(self, item_date):
        if item_date < {something}:
            raise ValidationError('')
        return item_date
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `item_date` parameter in the validator function will be the validated data of the whole `OrderItemSerializer` (`serializer.validated_data`).

Here is how it should be:

```
def validate_item_date(validated_data):
    if validated_data.get('item_date') < {something}:
        raise ValidationError('')
```

By using serializer-lever validation you can validated against other fields of the serializer:

```
def validate_item_date(validated_data):
    if validated_data.get('item_date') < validated_data.get('order_attr'):
        raise ValidationError('')
```

Of course you should handle None values and dates comparison properly here, this is simplified version of the code.

You can use class-based validator if you want to specify `{something}` statically.

```
class OrderItemValidator:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __call__(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        item_date = value.get('item_date')
        if item_date < self.a:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('')

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        validators = [OrderItemValidator(some_date)]
```

Be careful to not using something like that `OrderItemValidator(timezone.now())` here :).

You can also specify field level validator

```
item_date = serializers.DateTimeField(validators=[OrderItemValidator(some_date)])
```

In this case this field's validated data will be passed to the validator function instead of the whole serializer's validated data.